# two site collections, but groups only available in the first

Tags: site-collection, groups

I recently created a second site collection 'within' my first/root site collection. i.e.

My primary site collection is found at:

```
http://mysite.com
```

and the second one is at:

```
http://mysite.com/newSC
```

When I go to Site Permissions for the primary site collection I can search for group names, such as `Customers`, but when i try to find that same group in the second site collection I cannot find it (I get the red-underline, saying This entry was not found).

How can I access the primary site collection's groups from my second site collection?

I'm still researching, but wanted to ask the question sooner rather than later, as time of the essence.

Cheers

Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  SharePoint groups are only available to sites within the same site collection.  You can use AD groups if you want to have groups that span multiple site collections or farms.

Comment: Well, that certain explains a lot :) Thanks for info. As this is just one group, I'll recreate it (the group members are FBA roles, not individual people, making management easier). - CHEERS!